# MS Access: Selecting data from tables and showing it on form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm helping my friend with access even though I've never used it myself :) , so here is the problem:

We have two tables.

1st table has columns:

Event name, artist, event length

2nd table has columns:

Event name, manager

So the task is to show data from both tables in one table, but data should be displayed on a FORM named "Delegator" (i hope, that makes sense). Tricky part for us is, that we shouldn't use wizard, but have to use VBA code. Is there any command I can attach to form "Delegator" that would select desired data and show it on a form?

Comment: VBA? This is a database, you need to use SQL. Try using the wizard, and look at the SQL code. Learn some database  basics, learn some SQL, and come back to StackOverflow if you have a problem or get stuck later. (Unfortunately this is not a tutorial site.)

Comment: Anyway, create a query, and create a form based on that query. I don't see the VBA in this.

Comment: Thanks, I guess... :)

Answer (score 0):

While I understand the downvote for the OP, I also remember what its like to be so overwhelmed by a task that you don't even know where to begin.  As you have already experienced, Access is not for the entry level users.  With that, some understanding on relational databases is essential to make the application do what you're wanting it to do.  Rather than trying to explain it here, take a look at the following link to get a bit more insight on how relational databases work.

http://computer.howstuffworks.com/question599.htm

With that, to answer your immediate question you will need to perform a query, which essentially combines multiple fields of data into one table for easy viewing or other programmatic purposes based off of a common link (called a key), which in this case would be the Event Name.  This can easily be done using Query designer, but you say you must use VBA?  If so, there's more foundational learning that you'll need to do perform the task you're asking.

Also, am I correct in assuming this is for some sort of school work assignment?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Steve! We have managed to eventually google ourselves through all basics and achieve desirable result.